# Hide item selected in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a list such as

```
var items = [1, 2, 3];
var list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name 3'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'name 2'
  }
]
```

and I use li tag (not option) to show this list.

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in listName">
      <a ng-click="">{{name.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It will show 3 item and 3 list is same in a item.
Help me when I click name 1 of item 1, will hide name 1 of item 2, 3,... Click name 2 in item 2 will hide name 2 of item 1, 3...
Thanks

Comment: `ng-repeat="name in listName"`? I guess it should be `ng-repeat="name in list "`!

Comment: where are you using `item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
  $scope.list = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'name 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name 3'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'name 2'
  }];
  $scope.hideOthers = function(item, name){
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
    $scope.selectedName = name;
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in list">
          <a ng-click="hideOthers(item, name.name)" ng-show="!selectedItem || name.name !== selectedName || item === selectedItem">{{name.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You dnt need use variable `items` only for set loop count. It can make in `ng-repeat`;
2) You have error in variable name - `list`, not `listName`;

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3]">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in list">
      <a ng-click="name.select = i" ng-if="!name.select || name.select === i">{{name.name}}</a>
      <strike ng-if="name.select && name.select !== i">{{name.name}}</strike>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
3) Also use `$scope.list = //data` for broadcast data to template;